# Why isn't the javascript onclick function called?

Tags: javascript, onclick, alert

I have created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5c4Tn/17/) to describe the issue. Why isn't the alert displayed when I call the `doSomething()` function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to disable framework option in jsfiddle for javascript to work

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5c4Tn/22/)

```
function doSomething() {
  alert('Hello!'); 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is because `doSomething()` function is not defined in the HTML page. In jsfiddle your function (in js pane) is wrapped by document onload event of jquery. (see at the left side of jsfiddle for settings). So Its executed like this,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function doSomething() {
      alert('Hello!'); 
    }
});
```

See how its wrapped. Its not accessible. To fix it you should assign it to `window` object.
In the js pane write the function as

```
window.doSomething=function() {
  alert('Hello!'); 
}
```

It'll work

---

Its recommended you do not use `onclick` attributes of an HTML elements. Its better to assign event handler with JS.

```
$("img").click(function(){
  alert("Hello");
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the temporary down vote, SO acts weird on my phone.

Answer (score 4):

This is a "fiddle-thing". Pick `nowrap (head)` from the first selection in the "Choose Framework" field.

Answer (score 3):

What JsFiddle does for you is creating the `<HTML>`, `<head>` and `<body>` tags for you. You shouldn't include them in your HTML, because that would make the markup invalid after JsFiddle processed it. It also wraps your JS in the document's onload event. So your function was not defined in the root scope as you thought, but in th scope of the `document.onload` function, and you couldn't reach it from within the body, because that is outside of that function. I changed the JsFiddle attribute 'wrap in' to 'no wrap (head)' and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Your function `dosomeThing()` is not defined in the page
just replace header tag with this one

```
 <head>
    <script>
      function doSomething() {
  alert('Hello!'); 
}
    </script>
  </head>
```

and then try again

Comment: Isn't it the purpose of the JSFiddle Javascript box to help define those functions?

Comment: but you have not defined it in your HTML

Answer (score 0):

Here is your complete code. just copy and paste your editor. it is

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<title>Javascript Events</title>
<script type='text/javascript'>
window.onload = function() {
    var image_one = document.getElementById('imageOne');
    var image_two = document.getElementById('imageTwo');

    image_one.onclick = function() {
        alert('Hello!');
    }


    image_two.onclick = function() {
        alert('Hello!');
    }


}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <img id="imageOne" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0c/White_and_yellow_flower.JPG/320px-White_and_yellow_flower.JPG" />
    <img id="imageTwo" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/70/Example.png" /> 
</body>
</html>
```