# Change text color onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css, toggle

I have a toggle button and when I click the button I want to be able to change the colors of the text from a lighter color when not selected to black when selected. Right now it is only working on one of the buttons. Attached is a fiddle of my code. https://jsfiddle.net/h2db7qLp/

```js
function onContainerClick(event) {
  if (event.classList.contains('off')) {
    event.classList.remove('off');
  } else {
    event.classList.add('off');
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  background: #EFEFEF;
  position: relative;
  width: 126px;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-top: #CCC solid 1px;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  border-bottom: #EEE solid 1px;
  border-right: #ddd solid 1px;
  border-left: #ddd solid 1px;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}
.container2 {
  background: #EFEFEF;
  position: relative;
  width: 226px;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-top: #CCC solid 1px;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  border-bottom: #EEE solid 1px;
  border-right: #ddd solid 1px;
  border-left: #ddd solid 1px;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}
.switch {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.15s ease;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
.switch-title {
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.container.off {} .container.off .switch,
.container2.off .switch {
  left: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.container2.off .left-long,
.container.off .left-short,
.container2.on .right-long,
.container.on .right-short {
  color: #aaa;
}
.label {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 11px;
  z-index: 1;
  font: 16px"adiHaus", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: #000;
}
.label.right-long {
  left: 50%;
}
.label.right-short {
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="switch-title">Hand:</div>
<div class="container" id="container" onclick="onContainerClick(this)">
  <div class="switch" id="switch">
  </div>
  <div class="label left-short" onclick="onContainerClick(this)">L</div>
  <div class="label right-short" onclick="onContainerClick(this)">R</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I added the Javascript

Comment: Please have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14273784/2565294)

Comment: Why do you have event handlers on the L and R divs as well as the container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that by adding the class 'on' on change it goes well, also you don't need to call your handler on every div, just call once.

```js
function onContainerClick(event) {
  if (event.classList.contains('off')) {
    event.classList.remove('off');
    event.classList.add('on');
  } else {
    event.classList.add('off');
    event.classList.remove('on');
  }
}
```

```css
  .container {
  background: #EFEFEF;
  position: relative;
  width: 126px;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-top: #CCC solid 1px;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  border-bottom: #EEE solid 1px;
  border-right: #ddd solid 1px;
  border-left: #ddd solid 1px;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}    

.container2 {
  background: #EFEFEF;
  position: relative;
  width: 226px;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-top: #CCC solid 1px;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  border-bottom: #EEE solid 1px;
  border-right: #ddd solid 1px;
  border-left: #ddd solid 1px;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}    

.switch {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.15s ease;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}    

.switch-title {
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  font-size: 16px;
}    

.container.off {}    

.container.off .switch,
.container2.off .switch {
  left: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
}    

.container2.off .left-long,
.container.off .left-short,
.container2.on .right-long,
.container.on .right-short {
  color: #aaa;
}    

.label {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 11px;
  z-index: 1;
  font: 16px "adiHaus", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: #000;
}    

.label.right-long {
  left: 50%;
}    

.label.right-short {
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="switch-title">Hand:</div>
<div class="container on" id="container" onclick="onContainerClick(this)">
  <div class="switch" id="switch">
  </div>
  <div class="label left-short">L</div>
  <div class="label right-short">R</div>
</div>
```